# macOS project’s fonts are not scaling

Tags: macos, xcode

Issue: I’m creating a macOS app in Xcode and the fonts will not scale up and down. I have tried the target’s Mac, Mac Catalyst, and Mac (Designed for iPad). Neither of these targets will work.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new Xcode project.
2. Build and run the new project under any of the above mentioned Mac targets.
3. In Xcode tap on environment overrides
4. Notice that “Dynamic Type” is missing

Alternatively, after building the Mac app you can tap on “Format” from the toolbar of the app (on top left) and after hovering over “Font” the second menu
shows “Bigger” and “Smaller” short keys grayed out.

Lastly, after tapping on the toolbar: “Format > Font > Show Fonts” the Fonts menu will appear. Try toggling the font size… no changes.

**Expected result:** when adjusting font scale using methods given above, the font on the app should scale up and down accordingly.

**Actual result:** when adjusting font scale using methods given above, the font on the app remains unscaled.

**Question:** Am I supposed to implement some sort of font scaling API for Mac fonts to scale?

Comment: Our focus are end-user problems, so let‘s see whether there is a solution which doesn’t involve programming. If you don’t get answers in the next days, please **flag** for mod attention and we can migrate it to StackOverflow.

Comment: What version of XCode is this? Do you actually have an NSTextView? Is there a "Format" menu in the menubar? You should get that automatically, if required. If the font chooser isn't "plumbed in" to anything, then that may explain why it doesn't let you choose sizes. You certainly don't need to create your own font scaling routines.